# Text aligned to top and bottom of cell

Tags: css, html-table

Let's say I have code like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="top">top</div>
        <div id="bot">bottom</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to align #top to the top of the cell and #bot to the bottom through CSS.

```
#top { vertical-align:top; }
#bot { vertical-align:bottom; }
```

The above doesn't seem to work - it doesn't really seem to be having any effect at all. Here's a link to the code : http://jsfiddle.net/vKPG8/28/

Any explanations on why this is happening and how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vertical-align` is for inline elements and `div` is a block element. Try with `position: absolute` and `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`.

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```css
#top, #bot { position: absolute; }
#top { top: 0; }
#bot { bottom: 0; }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iyosac/1/edit
Check here for more info: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

#top, #bot { position: absolute; }
#top { top: 0; }
#bot { bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="top">top</div><br/>
        <div id="bot">bottom</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not cross-browser because according to CSS reference `position: relative` is undefined on table elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

Answer (score 7):

the accepted solution using position: absolute is not a cross-browser compatible solution for this problem, as Firefox doesn't (and according to the spec shouldn't) allow absolute positioning in table cells or elements with display:table-cell.

There doesn't seem to be a truly reliable css-only way of solving this problem, though I do have a css-only fix that works for this case. Essentially what I did is insert a before element that is tall enough to force the bottom line of text to the bottom since it has vertical-align: bottom set. This is essentially the same as putting padding-top, so it's not much of a solution.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Be7BT/

```
td {width:200px;height:100px;border:solid 1px;}
#top { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 100%;
}
#bot {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width: 100%;
}
#bot:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the height of the main td is not initially known (e.g. if it has a rowspan grater than 1 and its height is determined by other rows ?

Comment: No I don't think so. You'd probably have to set the height with javascrpit to make this a dynamic solution.

Comment: Thanks, it looks as though there is no nice cross-browser way to achieve this. I've tried a few approaches.

Comment: It is possible to achieve this with nested table and valign="bottom"

Answer (score 3):

I have a better idea, use nested table:

```
<table width="100px" height="100px" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">top</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=100%>
        <td valign="bottom">bottom
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This unfortunately also only works if the height of the outer table cell is preset.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is with `rowspan`:

```
<table><tr>
    <td rowspan=2>tall<br>tall<br>tall<br>tall<br>
    <td valign="top">top</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td valign="bottom">bottom</td>
</tr></table>
```